# How do I find out what Movie Clip contains the missing font Flash is complaining about?

Tags: flash

I have a fairly convoluted FLA with oodles of MCs that in turn have tons of text fields.  When I first fire up the IDE I get an error saying that there's a missing font and offering me my font list to substitute.  The thing is that I don't know where this font came from and would love to just set it correctly once and for all, but I just don't know what text field its in, and am unable to find it, just doing a manual search.

Is there some mechanism by which I can locate where this is set and change it?

TIA.

Comment: Just to make sure, do you mean a FLV or FLA ?

Comment: Which version of Flash are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the Movie Explorer (Alt+F3), check only the "text" button, type your font alias in the search bar and... tadaaaa

Comment: This only seems to work for objects that are on the stage, or am I missing something?

Comment: You could add all your library on the stage -go and have a coffee while it's processing- and then look at the Movie Explorer.

Comment: This seems like the right thing to do, and I can see it finding the fonts that I know are in there, but when I search for the font it complains about at start up, there doesn't appear to be any text field in there that has it.  Very odd!

Answer (score 1):

When you do "movie explorer", among all the different kinds of things to show, the last one is "Customize which items to show". Check "Symbol definitions" under the "Context" group did it for me.